# How to stop the agent when target is unreachable

Tags: unity, c#, ai

I want my player characters to stop when the target is unreachable.

Please watch [this video](https://smalltis.com/Images/ice_video_20220611-104228.mp4).

[image]

As you can see in this video, the agents don't stop when the target is unreachable.

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;
 
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
    public Camera cam;
 
    public NavMeshAgent agent;
 
    public ThirdPersonCharacter character;
 
    private LineRenderer linerenderer;
     
    bool isMoving = true;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        agent.updateRotation = false;
        linerenderer = GetComponent();
    }
 
    Vector3 hitPos = Vector3.zero;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
 
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
                agent.destination = (hit.point);
                hitPos = hit.point;
            }
        }

        if (agent.path.status == NavMeshPathStatus.PathInvalid || agent.path.status == NavMeshPathStatus.PathPartial) {
            character.Move(Vector3.zero, false, false);
            agent.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            agent.isStopped = true;
            agent.ResetPath(); 
            linerenderer.enabled = false;
        } else {
            character.Move(agent.desiredVelocity, false, false);
 
            linerenderer.positionCount = agent.path.corners.Length;
            linerenderer.SetPositions(agent.path.corners);
            linerenderer.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not stop them if the distance traveled in a certain time is lower than a set threshold?

Comment: @Zibelas tanx for your response, can you set an example for that? I'll accept that